# Editing older revision (not most recent) no longer includes older title and tags, and automatic rollback note

Tags: bug, status-deferred, edits, revisions-list, rollbacks

Say there are two revisions:

```
#2 mine
#1 OP [edit]
```

What used to happen, if I pressed edit next to the first revision, added stuff to #1 (not #2), they would be like this:

```
#3 rollback -- [manual comment if any]
#2 mine
#1 OP
```

That did not happen [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/84706/revisions) (#3) as it used to; moreover, the *OP title and OP tags* were **not** reverted, even though the editing page included them:

> [image]

Comment: I closed [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361831/doing-a-tag-only-edit-on-a-previous-revision-doesnt-do-the-expected-roll-back?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a dupe of this. There is a visible example in that, albeit of it being of the reverse. I edited a tag, and the body did not roll-back as expected.

Comment: Adding this to be looked into as a part of our bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report! ^_^

Comment: Hi @JNat: I think it (or part of it) has been fixed based on the [rollback I made here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/88709/revisions).

Comment: Will add a note about it for a dev to double check, @ymb1 — thanks!