# Doing a tag only edit on a previous revision doesn't do the expected roll-back

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

See the revision list of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/361827/revisions). I wanted to apply the changes done in revision 5 (a tag edit), on revision 3. So essentially a roll-back to revision 3, and then the edit that was made in revision 5 (latest version at the time).

The resulting revision 6 was an empty revision, without any changes.

**Expected:** a roll-back to revision 3 with the edits done in revision 5 applied to that version of the post.

Comment: Another related post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300454/339911

Comment: @Luuklag, using the [Timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/361827/timeline#history_69666508-06ff-43b3-bd95-6301fcbb5331) to view your edit displays three *loading dots* ("...") - making your edit *appear* empty, when in fact it can't be loaded (from the database). - I think this should remain open as a [tag:support] [tag:bug] tagged question. (From Review).